# Are these for controlling teh heat pumps with Wifi

Tags: untagged

We have 3 heat pumps (all ducted).  Yesterday I found 3 of these in the attic space.  Since they say Mitsubishi and Wifi, I am assuming that are Wifi controllers for the heat pumps.

The question is, are they really Wifi controllers.  And how do they work ?  They need to be wired to something.  Do they need additional hardware on the heat pump ?  Do they work with no indoor highwall unit ?

[image]

---

I just found an online installation manual to install it inside a [wall unit](https://www.mitsubishi-electric.co.nz/materials/Controllers/Manuals/WI-FI/1_Operation/Guide_Wi-Fi_Control_Installation_MAC-559IF.pdf).  I would still like to know if they can be used with the outdoor unit or the ducted system in the attic space.

Comment: Reading the manual i think you should first locate the port if it exists in any place if they exist then it should be a simple matter of running some jumper wires from this port To the controller and check if it flashes or connectible to router then you can probably double tape it somewher